# How can I achieve a similar look to this "2.5D"-ish art style?

Tags: camera, art

Recently I came across a game concept ([New Game Plus @ Superflatgames](http://superflatgames.com/wordpress/?tag=new-game-plus)) that used a very interesting "2.5D" art style where the world is in 3D and the characters & objects are in 2D (see image below).

I've experimented on and off for about a week now but I can't for the life of me replicate this camera angle/perspective and look. At first, I thought that this was as simple as doing a 3D world and having the characters in 2D but the 3d part looks really off. I then tried "tweaking" the 3D world in different ways such as tilting the 3D tiles away from the camera, because if you look at the top-left structure in the image it looks *slightly* tilted in the direction the camera is looking. But none of my experimentation thus far has yielded any results.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to replicate this? I know this art style exists in other games so maybe someone has implemented this before.

(Note that I am **not** asking about the pixel art look; that is simply 2D pixel art textures on 3D objects).

[image: art style]

Here is a picture of my latest attempt with the tilted tiles compared side-by-side with this image. As you can see, my tiles almost seem to tilt at a different angle. Unfortunately, I can't show all of my attempts as I haven't saved any screenshots of those.

[image: comparison]

If I put the camera higher and tilt it down a bit more, it's closer to the "PoV" of the original image, but as you can see on the very bottom grass tiles they are *super thin*, compared to the original image where the sides of the tiles are almost completely visible (almost as if they are tilted towards the camera).

[image: tilted]

Comment: Can you share pictures of your 3D attempts? I also think this is a 3D world with 2D characters

Comment: Added a comparison image. Not a very good one unfortunately, since my attempts haven't been very successful :P @user253751

Comment: And yes it's a 3d world with 2d characters, I'm aware :) I'm having issues replicating the perspective of the camera, my attempts look very off. I've tried adjusting FoV and such but to not much success.

Comment: Put your camera higher up and tilt it down more?

Comment: If tilting the camera more makes the vertical walls too not-vertical for your liking, you could instead experiment with shear matrices (change the Y based on the Z)

Comment: side note: cool style, I might have to use it in my game too

Comment: I added an image where I did this. As you can see the bottom tiles are super thin. I've added some shear as well, but it doesn't quite look normal? The numbered tiles are tilted (sheared).

Comment: Take a look at how the 2.5d legend of Zelda games work. The camera is above and tilted down, but the geometry itself is skewed to increase the appearance of depth. The characters themselves are also skewed so they appear more flat relative to the camera

Comment: @GaleRazorwind the picture is clearly 3D-rendered

Comment: You may also try a lower FOV and a more distant camera, which will make the view closer to orthographic. If you look at the sides of the screen in the other game and look at the slope of the front-to-back edges, and how they slope on the screen, they do not slope very much (still pretty close to vertical). By contrast, in your game they are closer to horizontal than vertical. The camera is clearly not orthographic, but it's *more* orthographic than yours.

Comment: Look at this effect to see what it looks like, when you change the FOV and then adjust the camera distance so everything doesn't get bigger or smaller: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolly_zoom

Comment: I am aware it is 3d rendered. So are the legend of Zelda 2.5d games like spirit tracks, phantom hourglass, links awakening 3d, a. Link between worlds.

Answer (score 10):

I tried to replicate the scene in Unity, so I'm using its reference system but this solution can be adapted for any other development environment as well.

This is the camera setup I used:

- **Position:** `(0, 13, -20)`, offset relative to the object the camera is following.
- **Rotation:** `(30, 0, 0)`, looking slightly downwards over the scene.
- **FoV:** `30` degrees.

Rotation is in degrees. The position values are based on the assumption that the level consists of blocks of 1 world unit in size:

[image]

While world blocks are placed normally around the scene, 2D objects such as characters, foliage and trees must take camera orientation into account. They must behave like billboards and align with the camera plane.

If the camera only moves and never rotates, this can be simply done by tilting 2D objects the same amount as the camera in the same direction, so that they will align to the view plane. They won't be affected by perspective distortions, apart from the apparent size due to distance from the camera:

[image]

This is the final result I got, I think it's very close to the original style you posted ([assets](https://opengameart.org/content/the-field-of-the-floating-islands) by Buch):

[image]