# For UE5 camera, how to add additional 2D transforms after perspective projection?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal-5

[image]

Octopath Traveler's camera seems to be always horizontal (All vertical lines keep parallel after projection), but the projection center is not at the center of the screen. So there must be additional 2D transform after perspective projection.

I would like to know if UE5 camera can do this. If not, how to do it?

Comment: This is called an oblique frustum, in case that helps your search.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for that. Now I find I need lens shifting or custom projection matrix. After some search, there seems no easy ways for UE to customize prjection matrix. What do you think about that?

Comment: As a non-UE user, I'm not the right person to ask.

Comment: Related question: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/200693/60302